# Rewrite url for subdirectory in .htaccess

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I moved wordpress files from root to a subdirectory. There are some files uploaded in wp-content/uploads folder. When accessing those files directly, I get a 404 error.

I need to rewrite the url only for the wp-content/uploads through .htaccess

What I need is to redirect from
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/report.pdf
to
http://example.com/wp_sub/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/report.pdf

This is what I've tried

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/wp_sub/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

This adds a subdirectory wp_sub to every link.
I need to add a subdirectory "wp_sub" only for wp-content/uploads links.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/wp_sub/$1
```

means:
You rewrite everything (`^(.*)$`) to `http://www.example.com/wp_sub/$1`.
Well, you don't want to rewrite everything, do you? :)

So we have to restrict this to only affect the `wp-content` folder:

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/.*)$ http://www.example.com/wp_sub/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Place this rule in your `/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp-content/uploads/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp_sub/$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code :

```
   RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/wp_sub/wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,L]
```